# How to tag the correct release or a recording using MusicBrainz?

Tags: xml, web-services, musicbrainz

I'm using the xml web service of MusicBrainz to fetch as much data as I can about every recording that I have. When quering Bohemian Rhapsody by Queen for example. What I get is this:[http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/ebf79ba5-085e-48d2-9eb8-2d992fbf0f6d?inc=artist-credits%2Breleases.](http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/ebf79ba5-085e-48d2-9eb8-2d992fbf0f6d?inc=artist-credits%2Breleases)
You can see that I get all the releases of the recording that are out there.

What I want is to know how can i distinguish between them. Which of them is the one that belongs to my release.

I know there must be some way to aproach this since the lookup tool in MusicBrainz Picard gives me only one of them. And its usually one from the middle and not from the beggining. Meaning there is some mechanizem that can pin-point the correct release.

Any ideas how its doing it?

Comment: What do you actually want? A recording ID or rather a track on a specific release? How did you get a specific MB recording id? Audio Fingerprint lookup? Picard also uses pre-existing metadata for the lookup. You must have something more than a recording ID, otherwise there is no `my release`.

Comment: Exactly as you described it. I've made an audio fingerprint lookup to get the MB recording ID, and with that ID I'm doing a lookup to the find the releasess the recording appears at. By now I've allready figured it out that I'll have to use pre-existing metadata from the track file. Thank you for the confirmation.